# No module named _tkinter on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I have a Django app that uses PIL

```
import PIL.Image
from PIL import ImageTk as itk
```

But when I deploy this app on Heroku, it gives me a traceback error or No module named "_tkinter" is found

I'm not using Tkinter but still, this is happening.

Comment: "I'm not using Tkinter"—sure you are. [`ImageTk`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageTk.html) uses Tkinter: "The `ImageTk` module contains support to create and modify Tkinter BitmapImage and PhotoImage objects from PIL images."

Comment: So even if I'm using tkinter under the hood, how can I deploy my application on Heroku?

Comment: You could try installing Tk and whatever other dependencies there are using the apt buildpack, but depending how you plan to use Tkinter it may not work anyway. There isn't much info here. Why are you using `ImageTk` instead of, say, `Image`?